# xCode iOS project. How to create a new project starting for an existing one

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

I am new to Xcode and iOS and going trough a course. Assignment 2 enhances Assignment 1, so I want to keep the project for Assignment 1 and build Ass2 starting from a copy from Ass1.

I had gone to the Finder an copy the folder that contains the project (for Ass1) and all related files then renamed the folder but not the files in it. Then double-click on the project file sitting in the copied folder. Doing some it seems Xcode sometimes get confused using files from the original folder. It is difficult to reproduce the error but the error appears again and again so I think it is not me doing something wrong.

Should I not create new projects this way? What is the best way to "duplicate" my project and all related files?

Comment: You've probably got absolute file paths being referenced somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just go on the folder of Assignment1, right click on it and select "Duplicate".
Then Rename the duplicated folder to Assignment2

Comment: This is exactly what I have been doing and I think it is causing the problems I said before.

Comment: this should be the solution.. so i think u should try it again from starting.